# Pandas-generated .tar.gz can't be extracted

Tags: python, pandas, tar

I have saved a pandas DataFrame to disk as a compressed .tar.gz file, using `data.to_csv(path+'file.csv.tar.gz', compression='infer')`, which seems to work fine. However, when I later try to extract the file using (on Ubuntu) `tar -xzvf file.csv.tar.gz`, I get the messages `tar: This does not look like a tar archive`, `tar: Skipping to next header`, and `tar: Exiting with failure status due to previous errors`. Why am I unable to extract this archive? Thanks.

Comment: _when I later try to extract the file using (on Ubuntu)_ Was the file also created on the same Ubuntu machine, or was it created on some other machine?  If it was created on another machine, how did you transfer the file?

Comment: Despite the filename, it's probably only a gzipped CSV, not actually a tar file. Can you gunzip it?

Comment: I am trying on the same computer on which it was made.

Comment: The `to_csv` docs says it can create a .tar.gz file by inferring the compression from the filename - "For on-the-fly compression of the output data. If ‘infer’ and ‘path_or_buf’ is path-like, then detect compression from the following extensions: ‘.gz’, ‘.bz2’, ‘.zip’, ‘.xz’, ‘.zst’, ‘.tar’, ‘.tar.gz’, ‘.tar.xz’ or ‘.tar.bz2’ (otherwise no compression)."